# Get data from two tables(join) with linq and return result into view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two tables: Projects and ProjectsData and I want to execute query with join and get the result in the View.

In the Controller I have this code:

```
ViewBag.projectsData = (from pd in db.ProjectsData
                                   join p in db.Projects on pd.ProjectId equals p.ID
                                   where pd.UserName == this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name 
                                   orderby p.Name, p.ProjectNo
                                   select new { ProjectData = pd, Project = p });
```

What I should use in the View to extract this data. I tried that:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.projectsData)
{
    @item.pd.UserName
}
```

but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In your view you are trying to access a `pd` property but such property doesn't exist. The property is called `ProjectData`.

This being said I would strongly recommend you to use view models and strongly typed views instead of `ViewBag`. This way you will also get Intellisense in your view which would have helped you pick the correct names.

So you could start by defining a view model that will hold all the information your view would need:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ProjectData ProjectData { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

and then inside your controller action populate this view model and pass to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = 
        from pd in db.ProjectsData
        join p in db.Projects on pd.ProjectId equals p.ID
        where pd.UserName == this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name 
        orderby p.Name, p.ProjectNo
        select new MyViewModel { ProjectData = pd, Project = p };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and finally inside your strongly typed view use the view model:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppName.Models.MyViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     <div>@item.ProjectData.UserName</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me for view model also. So that I can show two table data in a partial view and display that view in another database table View.

Comment: I did in the same way, but I received an exception: [InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+<JoinIterator>d__37`4[<>f__AnonymousType7`2[Auction,Winner],Auctioneer,Int32,<>f__AnonymousType8`5[String,DateTime,Decimal,String,String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TeAwaOnlineArtworkAuction.Entities.AuctionWinner]'.]

Comment: It seems that there is no easy way, we cannot avoid coding the transformation manually, take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160774/linq-join-query-how-to-display-new-table-in-view-mvc-c-sharp