# LINQ Query for fetching data from Multiple Tables

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I am working in **Asp.Net 4.0 C#-- *MVC-3***. I have one problem and don't know how to solve. I have 4 tables and want to fetch data from that tables with **LINQ**.

TABLES

**1) Project_Master**

```
    Field Names :   

    project_id (pk)
    project_name
    company_id (FK with company_master)
    company_category_id (FK with Company_Category_master)
    project_status_id (FK with Project_Status_Master)
```

**2)Company_Master**

```
   Field Names :

   company_id
   company_name
   company_category_id (FK with Company_Category_Master)
```

**3) Company_Category_Master**

```
   Field Names :

   Company_Category_Id
   Company_Category_Name
```

**4) Project_Status_Master**

```
   Field Name :

   Project_Status_Id
   Project_Status_Name
```

Below are the fields I need to fetch..(using LINQ Query)

1. **Company_Name**
2. **Total completed project using status id(1)=complete** (where staus 1 means completed)
3. **Total Project**
4. **Company_category_name**

So, how can I fetch data with linq query??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with MVC. Its all LINQ.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207382/get-data-from-two-tablesjoin-with-linq-and-return-result-into-view

Comment: Do you know what a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) is? There is also a `join` keyword for linq.

Comment: Stan, with linq please also use tags for linq provider (linq to sql, entity framework, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below example:

```
(From lse In Me.Leases, nty In Me.Entities, psg In Me.ProductionStages, lsg In LeaseStages _
        Where lse.LeaseName = leaseName _
        Select lse, lsg, nty, psg).Single
```

or you can use below example too:

```
var employeesQuery = from populationTable in db.Populations
join personTable in db.Persons on populationTable.Guid equals personTable.PopulationGuid
join employeeTable in db.Employees on personTable.Guid equals employeeTable.PersonGuid
select new { populationTable, personTable, employeeTable};
```

Comment: You can _also_ use? You should. The first example is a Cartesian product.