# Circular file references are not allowed for user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, user-controls, asp.net-4.0

I have created 3 user controls in three difference directories(Comment,Comment1,Comment2) like
Comment.ascx
Comment1.ascx
Comment2.ascx

Reference those as per give below:

Comment.ascx > Comment1.ascx
Comment1.ascx > Comment2.ascx
Comment2.ascx > Comment.ascx

And getting error like:

```
 Circular file references are not allowed.
```

As per some of forum I have set

```
batch="false"
```

in web config file but still I am getting error.
Is there any solution for that ?

Comment: var list = from a in users join b in country on a.countryid equals to b.countryid select new { a.username,c.countryname }

Comment: Please refere this link :http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/UXPF181012-SQL-Joins-with-C

Comment: Also refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207382/get-data-from-two-tablesjoin-with-linq-and-return-result-into-view

Comment: why loose focus while type in ace_wysiwyg editor in asp.net(you are using in brightable dashboard page),i'm not able to  typing in this editor i have put in another page any extra thing for that?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve the problem as [this](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/04/how-to-fix-circular-file-references-are.html) article mentions, although It's not recommended to use `batch= "false"` because of hurting the performance (Honestly I'm not sure about the authenticity) [What is batch used for?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.100).aspx)

In my Asp.Net Website project, there were some kind of conflicts between two or more WebUserControls, I had multiple user controls and they were placed in multiple folders, so I read the error message which Visual studio gave me.

it was referring to the source of error which was a usercontrol, I changed the user control file location and placed it in another folder, then I pressed `ctrl + shft + B` to build the project, this time I encountered a few errors saying there were some incorrect addresses to the WebUserControl, so I corrected the declarative address (which comes at the top of the Asp page), It was something like this:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/XFolder/Receiver.ascx" TagName="ReceiverProperties" TagPrefix="mdc" %>
```

I changed it to this one:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Receiver.ascx" TagName="ReceiverProperties" TagPrefix="mdc" %>
```

And built the project, everything was fine this time!

Personally, I have no idea if it's good or bad to add batch ="false" attribute since [this part of the book](https://books.google.com/books?id=1YLp0JDGwUMC&pg=PT515&lpg=PT515&dq=batch%20false%20performance&source=bl&ots=D3elRxf1ZW&sig=rrA0CooNU3gCH8UdOCpw0QRs8Mg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNvv6hyM_YAhXNu1MKHR-oDLAQ6AEIcDAJ#v=onepage&q=batch%20false%20performance&f=false) named `Asp.Net site performance secrets` suggests to apply it same as [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/perfworld/2010/01/13/how-can-i-disable-batch-compilation-for-my-asp-net-web-pages-so-that-the-first-user-accessing-the-web-site-doesnt-experience-slow-performance/)!

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the circular reference chain by putting the common code into a fourth assembly that can be used by the 3 user controls.

Comment: Can you please explain in brief ?

Comment: I have referenced first user control in .aspx page

Comment: Why does Comment2 need to reference Comment?

Comment: I am using the 3 level data hierarchy on third level I want to reuse that user control