# C# MVC ViewBag error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to C# MVC so please be patient.  I'm having some trouble displaying output for the ViewBag.  The application is a Fantasy Football webpage so I have three tables (right now, more to come) one for the basic player info (dbo.Player), one for player background (dbo.PlayerBackground), and one is just a definition table for the team (dbo.Team).

In one of my pages I have a name search and search by position and want to return information across these three tables.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var players = (from p in db.Players
                   join pb in db.PlayerBackgrounds on p.playerId equals pb.playerID
                   join t in db.Teams on p.teamAbbre equals t.teamAbbre
                   select new { playerID = p.playerId, playerName = p.name, position = p.position,
                                height = pb.height, weight = pb.weight, college = pb.college, dob = pb.dob,
                                imageUrl = pb.imageUrl, years = pb.years,
                                teamName = t.name
                                }).ToList();

    ViewBag.data = players;
    return View();
}
```

The query works fine but in index.cshtml I keep getting errors.

```
@foreach (var player in ViewBag.data)
{
    <tr class="success ui-dragable playerRow"  style="display: none;">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink( (string)player.playerName, "Details", new { id = player.playerID }, new { @class = "detailsLink" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @player.teamName
        </td>
        <td>
            @player.position
        </td>....
```

From the research I've done, this seems like it should work.  I've tried it both with and without the (string) cast.  Without the cast it gives me red squiggly saying I should cast and when I do I get:

> Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'playerName'

As I step through, I can watch player and it has the various properties just as it should.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an anonymous object. I can't really take the credit for that finding though, the answer I found was [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7652765/1832856) (Go give him an up-vote). Refer to it for complete details.

Essentially, the short of the story is that Anonymous objects are emitted as `internal` by the compiler. This causes problems when trying to use them as Razor views because they are compiled into a separate assembly by the ASP.Net runtime (`internal` only allows access in the same assembly).

So, the solution is to define a view model:

```
public class PlayerViewModel
{
    // Replace with the actual type of playerId
    public int playerId { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

And use it in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var players = (from p in db.Players
                   join pb in db.PlayerBackgrounds on p.playerId equals pb.playerID
                   join t in db.Teams on p.teamAbbre equals t.teamAbbre
                   select new PlayerViewModel { playerID = p.playerId, ... }).ToList();

    return View(players); // Use the strongly-typed model property for your view
                          // instead of ViewBag.data (It's recommended)
}
```

And finally in your view:

```
@* At the beginning of your view *@
@model IEnumerable<PlayerViewModel>
...
@foreach (var player in @Model)
    {

        <tr class="success ui-dragable playerRow"  style="display: none;">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(player.playerName, "Details", new { id = player.playerID }, new { @class = "detailsLink" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @player.teamName
            </td>
            <td>
                @player.position
            </td>....
```

Comment: Thanks Atin.  I just found this post as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207382/get-data-from-two-tablesjoin-with-linq-and-return-result-into-view, which helped a lot.  I was originally using a viewmodel but ran into problems getting the sql to work well.  
I still don't understand why my code wasn't working because I followed exactly what several other posters did.  Oh well, viewmodel is def the way to go.